# Click on ion-segment-button not show the contents of the page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Inside the header, I have two segment buttons, the first of which displays the contents as expected. The issue is that when I clicked on the second button, the screen contents disappeared, and when I clicked back on the first button, the contents disappeared completely as well.

The issue is only on iOS devices, so I have tried two solutions:

1. ChangeDetectorRef
2. event wrap-up with NgZone

But the error has not been fixed.

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
    <app-appheader-add></app-appheader-add>
    <ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="selectedSegment" (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)">
        <ion-segment-button checked value="employees" mode="md">
            <ion-label>Employees</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="managers" mode="md">
            <ion-label>Managers</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <div [ngSwitch]="selectedSegment">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'employees'">
            <ion-refresher slot="fixed" pullMin="80" pullFactor="0.3" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)"
                (ionPull)="doPull($event)" mode="ios">
                <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-down-outline" [pullingText]="pullingText">
                </ion-refresher-content>
            </ion-refresher>
            <div *ngIf="!hideNoResultScreen && 
        isPullRefreshVisible">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

TS:

```
    segmentChanged(event) {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.selectedSegment = event.detail.value;
        });
    
        if (this.selectedSegment == employees) {
         .....
          this.cf.detectChanges();
        } else if (this.selectedSegment == managers) {
          ......
          this.cf.detectChanges();
        }
      }
```

Comment: i think you don't have to use either of them. also share your html code? how are you hiding and showing html are you using `*ngIf`?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib no using ngSwitch, can you please explain why I don't have to use either of them

Comment: because you don't need them.
check this stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-bixzfu?file=src/app/app.component.html

Also share your HTML code you might be doing something wrong in ngSwitch.

Comment: You dont have a  *ngSwitchCase="'managers'"